# statement of argument principle(shakarchi)

Tags: complex-analysis

Shakarchi has the following statement of the argument principle:[image: page 1]

I understand the proof, but I am confused about the statement of the theorem.  It states that if 'if has no poles and never vanishes on C', implying that f has no poles or zeroes in C, but now equates the integral on the left with the number of zeros of f inside C - the number of poles of f inside C, implying that f has poles and zeroes in C.

What could I be missing?

Comment: [Argument Principle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgumentPrinciple.html).

Comment: C is a circle, inside C means the open disk.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is between "*on* $C$" (on the boundary) "*inside* $C$" (in the interior of the circle).

Comment: Thank you @angryavian. Why is this condition necessary? I can f is in the denominator.

Comment: @curious_analyst If $f$ has poles on $C$, then $f'$ is not well-defined. If $f$ has zeros on $C$, then $1/f$ is not well-defined.